# Unable to convert generic case class to json using "writes"

Tags: json, scala, playframework, playframework-2.2

I have a class which I want to be able to convert to json:

```
case class Page[T](items: Seq[T], pageIndex: Int, pageSize: Int, totalCount: Long)

object Page {

  implicit val jsonWriter: Writes[Page[_]] = Json.writes[Page[_]]
}
```

The error is `No apply function found matching unapply parameters`

Comment: Hi there, have you found a working solution? I'm having the same problem.

Answer (score 10):

You can define `Format[Page[T]]` for generic case class `Page[T]` like this:

```
import play.api.libs.json._
import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._

implicit def pageFormat[T: Format]: Format[Page[T]] =
  ((__ \ "items").format[Seq[T]] ~
    (__ \ "pageIndex").format[Int] ~
    (__ \ "pageSize").format[Int] ~
    (__ \ "totalCount").format[Long])(Page.apply, unlift(Page.unapply))
```

Although this solution requires more typing, it keeps your case class `Page[T]` clear of implicit parameter list or need to define concrete subclasses of `Page[T]`.

Comment: Thanks, this helped! Can you please explain what exactly happens in `unlift(Page.unapply)` bit?

Comment: this doesnt seem to work, I get this compile error
```polymorphic expression cannot be instantiated to expected type```\

Answer (score 5):

I'd prefer [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21374886/406435) with `trait`, but in case you do want to make your case class generic you could use one of 2 approaches.

In case you don't have to use `Page[_]`, i.e. you'll always call `toJson` on `Page[Int]` or `Seq[Page[String]]`, but not on `Page[_]` or `Seq[Page[_]]`:

```
object Page {
  implicit def pageWriter[T: Writes](): Writes[Page[T]] = Json.writes[Page[T]]
}
```

In case you have to serialize `Page[_]`:

```
case class Page[T](items: Seq[T],
                   pageIndex: Int,
                   pageSize: Int,
                   totalCount: Long)(
      implicit val tWrites: Writes[T])

object Page {
  implicit def pageWriter[T]: Writes[Page[T]] = new Writes[Page[T]] {
    def writes(o: Page[T]): JsValue = {
      implicit val tWrites = o.tWrites
      val writes = Json.writes[Page[T]]
      writes.writes(o)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: if the second case, where do I get `implicit val tWrites: Writes[T]` to provide to `Page(...)`?

Comment: @Alex: compiler will find it for you. You could just use `Page(Seq("abc"), 0, 1, 1)` and compiler will rewrite it as `Page(Seq("abc"), 0, 1, 1)(Writes.StringWrites)`. Object `Writes` is always in the search scope for implicit value of type `Writes[T]`.

Comment: The second approach causes the same error at `val writes = Json.writes[Page[T]]`.

Comment: and the first one also.

Comment: @Alex: I guess it's a bug in play. I'll try to fix it.

Comment: @Alex: this solution don't work - implementation of `Json.writes` is not fixed yet.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that you can have a generic writer for any type parameter. I propose following:

```
trait Page[T] {
  val items: Seq[T]
  val pageIndex: Int
  val pageSize: Int
  val totalCount: Long
}

case class IntPage(items: Seq[Int], pageIndex: Int, pageSize: Int, totalCount: Long) extends Page[Int]

object Page {
  implicit def jsonWriter = Json.writes[IntPage]
}
```

Comment: Well, that's a lot of repetition. I have a plenty of "models", each of them has "def all(...):Page[ModelClass]" function.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can write something like:

```
    case class Page(items: JsValue, pageIndex: Int, pageSize: Int, totalCount: Long)
```

Put the JsValue instead of the Seq[T]

here is my code example:

```
    case class ResponseObject(state:Int = 1,data:JsValue)

    case class City(id:Int,name:String,sort:String){
      require(id > 0)
    }

      def list = Action {
        implicit val cityFormat:Format[City] = Json.format[City]
        implicit val responseFormat=Json.format[ResponseObject]
        Ok(Json.toJson(ResponseObject(data=Json.toJson(City.list)))).as("application/json")
      }
```